# Pandas pivot_table: filter on aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I am trying to pass a criteria to the aggregate function to pandas pivot_table and I am not able to figure out how to pass the criteria to the aggfunc. I have a data table which is converted to pandas df.

The input table data:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | t1 | Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 102.2 |
| 2 | test1 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 101.2 |
| 3 | test1 | t1 | Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 102.3 |
| 4 | test1 | t1 | Dummy4 | result4 | 40 | 101.4 |
| 5 | test2 | t1 | Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 100 |
| 6 | test2 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 103 |
| 7 | test2 | t1 | Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 104 |
| 8 | test2 | t1 | Dummy4 | result4 | 40 | 105 |
| 9 | test3 | t1 | Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 102 |
| 10 | test3 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 87 |
| 11 | test3 | t1 | Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 107 |
| 12 | test3 | t1 | Dummy5 | result4 | 50 | 110.2 |
| 13 | test4 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 120 |
| 14 | test5 | t1 | Dummy6 | result1 | 100 | 88 |
| 15 | test1 | t1 | Dummy1 | result2 | 10 | 106.2 |
| 16 | test1 | t1 | Dummy1 | result6 | 10 | 101.1 |

I want to get the maximum on col7 data, but only when the maximum is greater than 100. If any of the col7 data is greater than the user defined criteria, then all the other columns data needs to be populated irrespective if the data met the criteria or not.

Tried the following:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    'col2': ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2',
             'test2', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5',
             'test1', 'test1'],
    'col3': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1',
             't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1'],
    'col4': ['Dummy1', 'Dummy2', 'Dummy3', 'Dummy4', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy2',
             'Dummy3', 'Dummy4', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy2', 'Dummy3', 'Dummy5',
             'Dummy2', 'Dummy6', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy1'],
    'col5': ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2',
             'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4',
             'result2', 'result1', 'result2', 'result6'],
    'col6': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 100, 10, 10],
    'col7': [100.2, 101.2, 102.3, 101.4, 100.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0,
             87.0, 107.0, 110.2, 120.0, 88.0, 106.2, 101.1]
})

res=df.pivot_table(values = 'col7', index = ['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns = ['col2'], fill_value = '', aggfunc = 'max' >= 100)
```

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Output should look like:

Max pivoted output without col5:

| col4 | col6 | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dummy1 | 10 | 106.2 | 100 | 102 | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy2 | 20 | 101.2 | 103 | 87 | 120 | N/A |
| Dummy3 | 30 | 102.3 | 104 | 107 | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy4 | 40 | 101.4 | 105 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy5 | 50 | N/A | N/A | 110.2 | N/A | N/A |

Max pivoted output including col5:

| col4 | col5 | col6 | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dummy1 | result2 | 10 | 106.2 | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 102.2 | 100 | 102 | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 101.2 | 103 | 87 | 120 | N/A |
| Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 102.3 | 104 | 107 | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy4 | result4 | 40 | 101.4 | 105 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| Dummy5 | result4 | 50 | N/A | N/A | 110.2 | N/A | N/A |

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Henry I updated the output table. I showed the final output on how it should look like which includes col4, col5, and col6 as indexes. I also showed an output without col5 which shows the max for each of the columns but when you add col5 into the mix, the table changes and that's what i try to depict and that's the final output i am trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @Henry thanks for the update. I need the table with col5. I just showed without col5 for reference only on how i am creating the table with col5 included. looks like i may have caused more confusion by adding table without col5 into the mix. The final output table i am looking for is the table below the comment "Max pivoted output including col5:" in op.

Comment: Again, I don't understand why `result6` is not in the result set. It is above the 100 threshold. That is the only point of difference between my output and your output... What are you looking for?

Comment: @Henry result6 is not in the dataset because it is not the highest. For Dummy1, we have three col5 values (result1, result2, result6) and out of all the three col5 values, we are trying to get only the highest which is 106.2. Let's say we have only one column to pivot which is "test1", then the output should be Dummy1-result2-10-106.2

Comment: Okay. I think you're saying that each group should have one entry and then you want to repopulate col5 with the value corresponding to the max. In that case, I don't understand why `Dummy1` has both a `result2` and `result1` in the output table?

Comment: @Henry Correct on each group should have one entry and repopulate col5 with the value corresponding to the max. The reason Dummy1 has result1 is when we get the max for test2, the col5 name corresponding to that max is result1. So, i need to go back to test1 and see if i have a value corresponding to result1 and if I have it populate it.

Comment: Okay. I don't understand. My perspective is that the result set would either include result 1 2 and 6, or just result 1. I don't think we're making progress in this format. I'd recommend opening a new question, and hopefully someone else can understand the correlation in a way that I cannot.

Comment: @Henry No worries. I will open a new  question. How would we update the code to show each group would have one entry and repopulate col5 with the value corresponding to the max? this would answer half of my question. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare the word 'max' to 100 via `>=` (`aggfunc = 'max' >= 100`):

I recommend not setting the fill value to a string, masking the DataFrame, to get rid of undesired rows, *then* replace with empty string via [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna):

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']
res = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'],
                     columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')
```

```
col2                 test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
col4   col5    col6                                   
Dummy1 result1 10    102.2  100.0  102.0    NaN    NaN
       result2 10    106.2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
       result6 10    101.1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Dummy2 result2 20    101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0    NaN
Dummy3 result3 30    102.3  104.0  107.0    NaN    NaN
Dummy4 result4 40    101.4  105.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
Dummy5 result4 50      NaN    NaN  110.2    NaN    NaN
Dummy6 result1 100     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   88.0
```

Mask for any values where [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas-dataframe-any) `res >= 100` and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna):

```
res = res[(res >= 100).any(1)].fillna('')
```

```
col2                 test1  test2  test3  test4 test5
col4   col5    col6                                  
Dummy1 result1 10    102.2  100.0  102.0             
       result2 10    106.2                           
       result6 10    101.1                           
Dummy2 result2 20    101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0      
Dummy3 result3 30    102.3  104.0  107.0             
Dummy4 result4 40    101.4  105.0                    
Dummy5 result4 50                  110.2
```

Optional [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) to clear the MultiIndex and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html#pandas-dataframe-rename-axis) to clear the axis name:

```
res[(res >= 100).any(1)].fillna('').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

```
     col4     col5  col6  test1  test2  test3  test4 test5
0  Dummy1  result1    10  102.2  100.0  102.0             
1  Dummy1  result2    10  106.2                           
2  Dummy1  result6    10  101.1                           
3  Dummy2  result2    20  101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0      
4  Dummy3  result3    30  102.3  104.0  107.0             
5  Dummy4  result4    40  101.4  105.0                    
6  Dummy5  result4    50                110.2
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    'col2': ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2',
             'test2', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5',
             'test1', 'test1'],
    'col3': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1',
             't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1'],
    'col4': ['Dummy1', 'Dummy2', 'Dummy3', 'Dummy4', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy2',
             'Dummy3', 'Dummy4', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy2', 'Dummy3', 'Dummy5',
             'Dummy2', 'Dummy6', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy1'],
    'col5': ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2',
             'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4',
             'result2', 'result1', 'result2', 'result6'],
    'col6': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 100, 10, 10],
    'col7': [102.2, 101.2, 102.3, 101.4, 100.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0,
             87.0, 107.0, 110.2, 120.0, 88.0, 106.2, 101.1]
})

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']
res = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'],
                     columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')
res = (
    res[(res >= 100).any(1)].fillna('').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
print(res)
```

---

To get the value without col5 remove it from the `index` of the `pivot_table`:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']
res = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col6'],
                     columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')
res = (
    res[(res >= 100).any(1)].fillna('').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

```
     col4  col6  test1  test2  test3  test4 test5
0  Dummy1    10  106.2  100.0  102.0             
1  Dummy2    20  101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0      
2  Dummy3    30  102.3  104.0  107.0             
3  Dummy4    40  101.4  105.0                    
4  Dummy5    50                110.2
```

Comment: I am not sure, if I was clear on my description as I am getting a different solution than what is desired when i ran it on the full dataset. Even though I am indexing on multiple columns, my intent was to get the max using col4 as index and the corresponding data for col5 and col6. Using the proposed sol, col4 "Dummy1" is repeated thrice because we have three unique col5 labels for Dummy1 but the intent is to get just 1 data point from col5 where col5 is max for the corresponding col4 "Dummy1". I have updated the output in the post. If you prefer, i can post as a separate question.

Comment: Since, no one else responded to the original question, I would appreciate if you can take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
res = df.assign(col7 = df.col7.where(df.col7 > 100)).pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'],
                     columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max', fill_value= '')
```